# Can't Insert Into Database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a database, and I can't insert values into it. Here's my database and my code.

Can you tell me what my problem is?

The output tell me that my sql syntax is wrong. However, I can add values from phpmadmin without any problems.

When I use code, I fail. And, I couldn't find any proble.

Thank yuy very much.

[DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEaPv.png)

```
<?php

$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "pass";
$db = "rmado";
$db_server = "localhost";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($db, $db_handle);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    $title = $_POST['username'];
    $desc  = $_POST['password'];
    $aaa   = $_POST['type'];
    $bbb   = $_POST['email'];

    $query = "insert into users(username, password, type, email) values ($title, $desc, $aaa, $bbb)";

    mysql_query($query);
}

?>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="login_form">

        <form name="login_form" method="post" action="zort.php">

            username: <input name="username" type="text" value="">
            password: <input name="password" type="text" value="">
            type: <input name="type" type="text" value="">
            email: <input name="email" type="text" value="">


            <input name="addtask" type="submit" value="add task">

        </form>

    </div>
    <!-- end login_form-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

id: int(5)

title: varchar(30)

desc: varchar(50)

assigner_id: int(5)

assignee_id: int(5)

creation_date: date

due_date: date

status_id: int(5)

category_id: int(5)

and here's my php code:

```
$query = "insert into tasks (title, desc, assigner_id, assignee_id, creation_date, due_date, status_id, category_id) values ('$title', '$desc', $ass1, $ass2, '$cre', '$due', $stat, $cat)";
```

Where's wrong in this code? Thank you very much.

Comment: you are missing ' quotes. but you have much bigger problems. Use prepared queries.

Comment: Try using mysqli , check this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Please, escape your query and don't use deprecated mysql_* functions. Quotes missing definitively! And Why on earth are you using text columns for username and password etcetera...

Comment: 1. Why are you using a deprecated library? 2. SQL injection have you heard of this? 3. Why not check for errors in the various functions

Comment: Now, I can add to my users table, but I can't add to my other table. This is my query: `$query = "insert into tasks(title, desc, assigner_id, assignee_id, status_id, category_id) values ('$title', '$desc', '$ass1', '$ass2', '$stat', '$cat')";` The same type of code works in users table. Can my database is different type? The int, text and timestamp? [Link to my db image:](http://i.imgur.com/iijakr8.png)

Comment: For a start the fields that are integers do not require the quotes. In fact it might work without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your original question: all those fields are text in your table. You're not encapsulating your values with quotation marks in your original query for these text fields. That is, the following will work for your example:

```
$query = "insert into users (username, password, type, email) values " .
         "('$title', '$desc', '$aaa', '$bbb')";
```

This will let MySQL know what strings you want inserted for those fields.

*However*, there are several issues with what you have on this page. A malicious user could put some MySQL-acceptable strings into these fields and those could cause harm to your database. You need to escape your input strings to prevent malicious content from damaging your database.

Considering using also [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as you are using a deprecated library. See [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) for some examples.

Also, your fields should not be text fields. They really should be varchars and you should limit their length.

#### EDIT

Your second query needs to encapsulate `desc` with backticks because `DESC` is a reserved MySQL word for descending.

Comment: Can you look at my comment on the upper part? Thank you very much.

Comment: In your database, status_id and category_id are not text fields in your table. They are integer fields. Thus, you should not have the single quotation marks surrounding them. You should also validate whether what you receive are indeed integers.

Comment: I still can't insert data. I use ' when inserting varchar(N) data. No ' when inserting int(N) data. I tried both ' and no ' when inserting date. I still can't insert any data. I can insert data when I'm using phpmyadmin, but not with my php code. users table has no problem, but this one does not work. :/ What must I do?

Comment: The assigner_id and assignee_id are also integer fields, which I neglected to see. Try using `echo $query;` in PHP to see the query as it will be sent to the MySQL driver. You can run this query with the "query" option in phpmyadmin and it can tell you the error you have.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I still can't do it. I updated my post. Can you please check it? I'm really sorry to waste your time.

Comment: The output of my query is correct. Which is: `insert into tasks (title, desc, assigner_id, assignee_id, creation_date, due_date, status_id, category_id) values ('test title', 'test desc', 1, 2, '2020-01-01', '2020-09-09', 1, 1)` And, I updated my post. Can you take a look at it again? Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to encapsulate `desc` with backticks like so: `\`desc\``. This is because `DESC` is a keyword for descending when ordering your queries. Thus, your query should be `INSERT INTO tasks (title, \`desc\`, assigner_id, assignee_id, creation_date, due_date, status_id, category_id) VALUES ('test title', 'test desc', 1, 2, '2020-01-01', '2020-09-09', 1, 1)`.

Comment: Oh God... At last... Silly me. Thank you very much. Thank you very very much. I can't sleep for hours because of this, and now I see it's really a dumb problem. Thank you very much man. I hope I can do more than saying thanks. Thank you very much...Oh... I'm so happy right now.

Comment: Of course. Thank you very much for your help again. Take care. I hope someone else will make you happy like you made me.